# Max-height workaround for IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

In the photography portfolio linked below, clicking on individual images renders the photo at a max-height of 90% of the browser window. In Safari, Firefox, and Chrome. But IE9 seems to ignore this command entirely and the user must scroll to see any portrait oriented photo in its entirety.

I've googled workarounds, but haven't found any that apply to IE9. Mostly I found Javacript expressions in the stylesheet suggested as workarounds for IE6. Is there a less "expensive" workaround for IE9? Or is it no longer a problem (which is why I can't find anything) and I just have a browser setting wrong?

Here's an example of an image that renders properly in Chrome, Firefox, & Safari - but you have to scroll in IE9: http://russmoorephotography.com/#/portfolio/state-capitol-aisle-capitol-dome/

Edit: this actually doesn't work in Firefox either. Just Chrome & Safari.